# Watson retrieve and rank: document relevance score

Tags: solr, relevance, watson, rr

How do I call Solr to return relevance scores in the result? I want to have a Solr document that includes the confidence that Solr uses internally for ranking, but I don't want to have to make a separate call to the ranker?

I tried to add the "confidence" field to the list of fields to return, but it doesn't have any data.

```
query.set("fl","id,title,fileName,contentHtml,searchText,sourceDocId,confidence");
query.set("debugQuery" ,true);
```

Comment: I reworded the question a bit to try to make it a little clearer.  Things that are still not obvious: is there anything here that is Watson specific, or is it just dealing with the Solr API? Is the 'ranker' a part of the Solr or Watson API?  I am not familiar with it.  The question could also use an example of what comes back from the query in CSV, JSON, or XML -- I assume you have access to the URL and can query the index directly

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I'm not familiar with both services.                          As I understood Watson RR is added on top of Apache Solr to rerank the results of a query with a ranker. My task was to perform a query without the ranker and with the ranker to explore the differences. I found the answer for my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `score` in fl, which adds relevancy score value calculated for each document in the resultset.

```
query.set("fl","id,score,title,fileName,contentHtml,searchText,sourceDocId,confidence");
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the solution that I needed :)

Comment: welcome. Upvote or accept answer if you found my answer usefull. thank you